# How to trigger scroll of container by scrolling outside of said container

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Here's my dilemma: I have a container of content that runs in the centre of my window. Outside of this container is a grey background that gets larger or smaller depending on how big the window size is. The issue I'm having is that I'm not able to scroll up/down this central container if the mouse is outside the container (it does work fine if the mouse is in the container). I would like to achieve the effect you see in Google documents or this site [here](http://wirelessnerds.ca/products/phones/). So basically, I'd like to be able to scroll this container from any point in the window. Some things I have already attempted: binding a mouse scroll to the whole body--this does work, but the issue is that there is no detection on mobile. Binding scroll to the body doesn't seem to work either as the body is technically static--it's just the content within it that goes down the page.

Here's some sample code of my template below (nonhome_container is what I would like to get scrolling):

```
  </pre>
  <div class="full-width" id="content">
    <?php
   // Run the page loop to output the page content.
   if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">>
        <div id = "nonhome_container">

            <div id = "nonhomecontent_container_small">

                 <?php if ( ! is_front_page() ) { ?>
                    <h2 class="entry-title">
                      <?php the_title(); // Display the page title ?>
                    </h2>
                 <?php } ?>
                 <div id = "nonhome_linebreak"></div>

                    <div id="contact-content">
                      <?php the_content(); 
                      // This call the main content of the page, the stuff in the main text box while composing.
                      // This will wrap everything in p tags
                      ?>
                      <?php wp_link_pages(); // This will display pagination links, if applicable to the page ?>
                    </div><!-- the-content -->

                <div id = "nonhome_linebreak"></div>

            </div>

         </div>
      </article>
      <!-- #post-## -->

   <?php endwhile; ?>

  </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ - You could use that, then use jquery to also jump between different elements inside the container.

Comment: I did try that but binding scroll to the body doesn't work because there's nothing to scroll down on. So the listener doesn't get triggered.