# Capturing mouse wheel while preventing page scroll in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to capture mouse wheel events while the mouse is on a div or on elements within the div, and prevent the page to scroll.

There are some solutions in this forum (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281244/capturing-scroll-wheel-events) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313142/javascript-capture-mouse-wheel-event-and-do-not-scroll-the-page)) but the page keeps scrolling.

The solution must be pure JavaScript (i.e. no jQuery or the like).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to cancel the event after capturing it.

```js
// This disables the event for the entire document.
// Substitute a reference to the DOM element you wish to 
// deal with instead of "document" below.
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", function(evt){

  console.log("mousewheel event detected");

  evt.preventDefault(); // Cancel the event
  evt.stopPropagation() // Don't bubble

});
```